# Using the definition, prove that following limit exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

> Suppose that $x_n$ is a sequence of real numbers that converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. Using the definition, prove that following limit exists.
> $$\frac{x^2_n − e}{\sqrt{n}}→ 1 − e \quad\text{ as }\quad n \to\infty.$$

Here is my attempt, but I'm not sure. If it is wrong give me hint to prove that's enough.

**My Attempt**

By hypothesis, given $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|x_n-1|<\epsilon$.

Next, apply $\epsilon=1$ to choose $n\geq N_2$, which implies $|x_n-1|<1$ (i.e $x_n<2$).  So,

\begin{align}\left|\frac{x^2_n − e}{\sqrt{n}}- (1 − e)\right| &=\left|\frac{(x_n −1)(x_n +1)}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1-e}{\sqrt{n}}-1 +e\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{(x_n −1)(x_n +1)}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{(1-e)(1-\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}}\right|\\
&\leq \left|\frac{(x_n −1)(x_n +1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right|+\left|\frac{(1-e)(1-\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}}\right|.
\end{align}

Since $|1-e|<2$ and given $ϵ>0$, there is an  $N\in\mathbb{N}$  such that $n≥N$ implies $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|\lt \epsilon$ so choose $n≥N_1 $ implies $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\lt 1$ so
$$\left|\frac{x^2_n − e}{\sqrt{n}}- (1 − e)\right|<\left|\frac{(x_n −1)(x_n +1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right|+2$$ since $x_n+1<3$ set $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$

$$\left|\frac{x^2_n − e}{\sqrt{n}}- (1 − e)\right|<3|x_n-1|+2<3\epsilon+2$$

Thank you!!!

Comment: I made some edits to your question to make it easier to read.  For future reference, the commands `\begin{align}...\end{align}`, `\sqrt{n}`, and `\left|...\right|` make a big difference.

Comment: I know this is not correct since $<3\epsilon+2$ but how to prove

Comment: @DMcMor thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove that, since it is not true. In fact, since the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded (since it converges), then so is the sequence $(x_n^{\,2}-e)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^{\,2}-e}{\sqrt n}=0.$$Concerning your attempted proof, note that, at the end, you get$$\left|\frac{x_n^{\,2}-e}{\sqrt n}-(1-e)\right|<3\varepsilon+2.$$So what? You should have got$$\left|\frac{x_n^{\,2}-e}{\sqrt n}-(1-e)\right|<\varepsilon$$instead.

Comment: Is there anything to say at the end of my proof?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad I could help.